# expected while before elseif

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

I don't know why it says it needs a while or where to put it, and it gives the wrong answer for the LOCS function also is there anything i can do about the default pointer warning. this is just a start i will be extending this later so it would be a big help and i have tried while (%s != '\0')

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SQUARE(x) x * x

float LOCS (float a, float b, float c) //Law Of CoSines
{
float d, e, f, g;
 d = SQUARE(a) + SQUARE(b);
 double cos (double);
 double sqrt (double);
 e = 2 * (b * a);
 f = d - (e * cos(c));
 g = sqrt(f);
 return g;
}
float PythagoreanTherom (float a, float b) 
{
float c, result;
    double sqrt (double);
        c = SQUARE(a) + SQUARE(b);
        result = sqrt(c);
return result;
}
int main (void)
{
float sidea, sideb, angle, result;
char array[81];
float LOCS (float a, float b, float c);
float PythagoreanTherom (float a, float b);
printf("Type what you would like to do\n");
 scanf("%s", &array[81]);
if (array[81] = "LawOfCosines") do {
printf("Print the two known sides then the angle \
 pressing enter after each.\n");
scanf("%f", &sidea);
scanf("%f", &sideb);
scanf("%f", &angle);
 result = LOCS(sidea,sideb,angle);
 printf("The third side is %f", result);
 }
 elseif (array[81] = "PythagoreanTherom") do {
 printf("Type enter after the \
input of each leg\n");
    scanf("%f", &d);
scanf("%f", &e);
    f = pt(d,e);
printf("The hypotenuse is %.2f", f);
}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Horrible formatting! This is no doubt leading to much of your confusion.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &array[81]);`—good. It shouldn't be the end user who decides if an overflow happens, instead, make it happen unconditionally.

Comment: @mafso well, the user could send EOF to prevent the overflow!

Comment: There's no single `elseif` keyword in C, probably you meant `else if` (notice the space).

Comment: `elseif (array[81] = "PythagoreanTherom") do {`, where `do` does not indicate a loop, must be the most errors per word (token) I've ever seen in "serious" code. Literally, `elseif`, `[81]`, `=`, the string being misspelled, and extraneous `do`… that's about one mistake per two programming symbols. Fortunately the brackets, parens, and braces match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This code. I have made some changes in your code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<string.h>
#define SQUARE(x) (x) * (x)
float LOCS (float a, float b, float c) //Law Of CoSines
{
    float d, e, f, g;
    d = SQUARE(a) + SQUARE(b);
    double cos (double);
    double sqrt (double);
    e = 2 * (b * a);
    f = d - (e * cos(c));
    g = sqrt(f);
    return g;
}
float PythagoreanTherom (float a, float b)
{
    float c, result;
    double sqrt (double);
    c = SQUARE(a) + SQUARE(b);
    result = sqrt(c);
    return result;
}

int main (void)
{
    float sidea, sideb, angle, result,d,e,f; // you didn't declare the d,e,f variables
    char array[81];
    float LOCS (float a, float b, float c);
    float PythagoreanTherom (float a, float b);
    printf("Type what you would like to do\n");
    scanf("%s",array);
    if (strcmp(array,"LawOfCosines")==0){   // no need of do while loop here // for comparing two strings you should not use == operator to compare. use string functions or implement your own function
            printf("Print the two known sides then the angle \
                            pressing enter after each.\n");
            scanf("%f", &sidea);
            scanf("%f", &sideb);
            scanf("%f", &angle);
            result = LOCS(sidea,sideb,angle);
            printf("The third side is %f", result);
    }
    else if (strcmp(array, "PythagoreanTherom")==0){   // no need of do- while loop here
            printf("Type enter after the \
                            input of each leg\n");
            scanf("%f", &d);
            scanf("%f", &e);
            f = PythagoreanTherom(d,e); // call the function with the same name as it is in definition
            printf("The hypotenuse is %.2f", f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While compiling your code link with `-lm` because you are using math library.

```
cc filename.c -lm
```